# Is this right to use private inheritance?

Tags: c++

```
class NotCopyable
{
public:
    NotCopyable() { }
private:
    NotCopyable(const NotCopyable&);
    NotCopyable& operator = (const NotCopyable&);
};

class BasicTimer : private NotCopyable
{
public:
      ...
}
```

Is this right to use private inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a perfectly acceptable - and even common - use of private member visibility. That will keep you from copying a `NotCopyable`, or anything that derives from it, around.

Comment: Why not declare NotCopyable(){} private in base class?

Comment: @Kim: If you don't have some constructor which has at least protected accessibility (after considering `friend` modifiers), then no object of a derived class could ever be constructed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Boost does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor of NotCopyable is public, so it will always be available in derive class whether this class is inherited as private, public or protected.So private inheritance is not doing anything special here

Answer (score 0):

That's perfectly ok and even recommended.

The well-designed boost library provides boost::noncopyable, which essentially does exactly that. It makes your code better readable. Who wants to put this

```
class Bla
{
    // bla bla bla...

private:
    Bla( const Bla & ); // not implemented.
    Bla & operator=( const Bla & ); // not implemented.
};
```

when you can simply write the following?

```
class Bla : boost::noncopyable
{
    // bla bla bla...
};
```